# How can I edit or unprotect a single cell in a protected Excel sheet from C#?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop, ms-office

I'm trying to manipulate an excel file with C# by using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.
The workbook I'm trying to manipulate has shared protection between users.

I have the file password and I have the password of the cells which I want to access and edit.

If I try to do that from Excel, I do the following:

- open the file, type the password
- go to a cell, double click on a cell to edit.
- a dialogue appears, asking me to provide the password, I provide the password and then I can edit.

I want to do this from a C# application.

My current code is as following:

```
xl.Application excelApp = new xl.Application();
excelApp.Visible = true;
xl.Workbook newworkbook =
    excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\1.xls", 0, false, 5, "password", "", false,
                            xl.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true,
                            false, false);
xl.Sheets excelSheets = newworkbook.Worksheets;
xl.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (xl.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item("Sign On_Off");
excelWorksheet.Select(true);
xl.Range myrange = excelWorksheet.get_Range("b16", "b16");
myrange.Value2 = "testing";
```

The last line gives me this error message:

> The cell or chart that you are trying to change is protected and therefore read-only.

I can't unprotect the whole sheet cause that would mean I will have the file opened exclusively for me only and other users can't save changes.

So my question: Is is there is way I can unprotect a cell only?

I imagine something like:

```
myrange.unprotect("pw");
```

Answer (score 1):

`Protect` is just available to [`Workbook`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.protect.aspx) and [`Worksheet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.protect.aspx) classes.

Alternatively, you can try to work with [`Worksheet.Protection Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.protection.aspx):

```
ActiveSheet.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add _
    Title:="Range123", Range:=Range("K4:L10"), Password:="123"
```

Comment: thanks , but how do i edit a cell without unprotecting the whole shared workbook i mean with excel i simply click on the cell and type my pw for this cell, and then its editable, 
every user have different pws for different cells, 
i should be able to do that without haveing the pw for the protected shared workbook, since i can do it from excel

Comment: thank you so much , here is what i have tried :
excelWorksheet.Activate();
xl.Range myrange = excelWorksheet.get_Range("b16", "b16"); excelWorksheet.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add("Title", myrange, "1");
 it generate an error : Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know to here go from there =(

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had time to try it, but [this paragraph](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/0596007663/998) looks like what you are looking for. It seems that the VBA equivalent object you are looking for is [ActiveSheet.Protection.**AllowEditRanges**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213690(office.11).aspx), which stores information about the areas that can be edited by users in a sheet.
One thing you might want to look into as well is the [**UserInterfaceOnly**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/810788) option on ActiveSheet.Protect. You can protect a range with a password for users, but access it without password through macros.